# How can we add the custom vibration pattern from our iPhone to pass in our app programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to add the **custom vibration pattern** from my iPhone and want to pass that vibrate in my application programmatically.

This is the line I'm calling from my code for vibration to occur:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

But the above code is producing only the default vibration. I want to add the custom vibration pattern which I have in my iPhone to access inside my app or adding a custom vibration pattern inside the code.

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?

Comment: This is the line i'm calling from my code for vibration to occur:   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);                        But the above code is producing only the default vibration.I want to add the custom vibration pattern which i have in my iphone to access inside my app or adding a custom vibration pattern inside the code.Need any suggestions regarding this.